# How to interpret the “surface power density” of a battery/capacitor

Tags: power, batteries, supercapacitor, units

I’ve come across [this research](https://www.nature.com/articles/ncomms4026) and one point of representing a power output confuses me:

> This enzymatic fuel cell is based on non-immobilized enzymes that exhibit a maximum power output of 0.8 mW cm−2 and a maximum current density of 6 mA cm−2, which are far higher than the values for systems based on immobilized enzymes.

**When we mentions a power output or power density in terms of “power/area”, what exactly do we mean?** What exactly is this “area”? Should this be the surface area of the battery, or should we consider some deeper structures (say a graphene battery/capacitor may have a lot of layers, should the area of all the layers be considered when calculating?)?

Comment: I would ask in a chemistry forum.

Comment: I'd guess that power/unit area is a fuel-cell specific measure and probably relates to the area of the exchange membrane. Not something directly comparable to batteries or capacitors. Power/volume or power/mass are more typical measures.